# Error while creating db in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, sqlite

I am creating an app in IOS with cordova 2.1.0 framework. I am creating sqlite3 db in objective-c with following code:

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
self.databaseFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"splistdb.sqlite3"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;


if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databaseFile]) {
    /*[fileManager copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FriendsDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite3"] toPath:dbFileName error:&error];*/
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splistdb" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
    NSLog(@"doc path=%@",path);
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:self.databaseFile error:&error];
    [self createConfigTable];
    NSLog(@"database created");
} else {
    NSLog(@"fail to create database");
}
```

I have included libsqlite3.dylib file in build phases heading. But i am getting following error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil'
```

What could be wrong in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that `path` is `nil`, probably because the file `splistdb.sqlite3` is not being copied into the application bundle.  Make sure that it is in your project, and has been added to your target application.

Answer (score 0):

most probably this line gives you nil value

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splistdb" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
```